# Why do imports break in apache/mod_wsgi but not in development?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, importerror

I was very near desperation trying to solve this issue, so I thought I would share my new knowledge here.

#### The Setup

```
mysite/
 |-myapp/
 |   |-views.py
 |   |-urls.py
 |   |-models.py
 |   `-foo/
 |      `- bar.py
 `-mysite/
    |-settings.py
    `-...et cetera
```

**views.py**

```
from foo.bar import barclass
```

#### The Symptoms

My django project worked fine in development but an import statement in `views.py` (*not* a problem with settings import and *not* a problem with the PythonPath in mod_wsgi as many other questions have asked!)

```
ImportError: No module named bar
```

I repeat: not a settings problem and not a wsgi configuration problem, yet it worked fine in development and broke in production.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Solution

File permissions.

`foo` and all its subdirectories had permissions set to 700. Its files (bar.py, etc) all had permissions 644.

Changing permissions to 755 and 664, respectively, fixed the error. I thought that apache is always run as root, so I am still a bit confused about the whole thing.

Comment: Running your code as root would be a huge security issue. Apache will switch processes that run your code to a special Apache user before even loading your code. That special Apache user therefore needs the ability to access your code.